# Strictly decreasing ${a_n}$ such that Alternating Series diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find strictly decreasing ${a_n}$ such that ${\displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n}$ diverges.

I came up with $a_n = \begin{cases}\ 7 & \text{if }n \text{ = 0}\\ 3 + \dfrac1{n} & \text{if } n \text{ = 1,2,3... }\end{cases}$

Is it correct? If no, then what strictly decreasing ${a_n}$ would fit in?

Comment: Google the alternating series test.

Comment: I think your series reduces to $(-1/n)^n$, so it still converges.

Comment: Can you find a formula for the partial sums $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and then find the limit (if it exists) $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n.$

Comment: What you chose is fine. All you need is that the limit of the sequence is nonzero. Since your sequence converges to $3$, you're done

Comment: @TinPhan: His sequence doesn't converge to $0$, so the series can't converge. And how did you get a factor $n^n$ anyway?

Comment: @Clayton Yes, you're right. Even though the 3's "cancel", it still diverges. :)

Comment: You're right because $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works.

Note that $S_2=7-\left(3+\frac{1}{1}\right)+\left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)=7-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and that in general 
$$S_{2n}=7-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$
so that for the even partial sums $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=7-\ln(2)$.
However the odd partial sums approach a different limit.
Note that $S_3=7-\left(3+\frac{1}{1}\right)+\left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)=4-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)$ and that in general for $n>0$
$$ S_{2n+1}=4-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$
so that for the odd partial sums $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n+1}=4-\ln(2)$.

Since two subsequences of the sequence of partial sums converge to different limits, the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = \begin{cases}\ 7 & \text{f }n \text{ = 0}\\ 3 + \dfrac1{n} & \text{if } n \text{ = 1,2,3... }\end{cases}$$

For an alternating series with positive decreasing terms, we ask if $\sum_k (a_{2k}-a_{2k+1})$ diverges.  Here $$a_{2k}-a_{2k+1} = {1\over 2k}-{1\over 2k+1}={1\over 2k(2k+1)}$$  The sum $\sum_k (a_{2k}-a_{2k+1})$ *converges* because $1/k^2$ does.

An easy choice for you is $a_n=-n$.  That makes $a_{2k}-a_{2k+1}=-(2k)+(2k+1)=1$.  But maybe you had a different notion of decreasing in mind.  Consider for example Baby Rudin 3.42.